# Chrome paragraph word wrap break word

Tags: css, google-chrome

Is it possible to force Chrome to break words when wrapping text in paragraph?

I tried:

`white-space:pre-wrap` - nothing happens

`word-wrap: break-word` - nothing happens

`both of above` - nothing happens

[JS Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/wa3kz/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `word-break: break-all;` instead of `word-wrap: break-word;`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7F7a5/)

Answer (score 2):

'**word-break:break-word;**' (works on webkit and blink browsers) is a better solution because it doesn't break atbitrarily but only if necessary (e.g. in case of one long string not separated by spaces that exceeds the allowed width limits)